# Document query selector returns null, when trying to remove or add class, but works fine on adding attributes

Tags: javascript

I have a implemented a scrollSpy functionality on my page. What I am wondering is, why do I get `null` when I do a query select, and try to remove or add class 'active', but it finds the element, when I am setting the attributes?
So, this works fine:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  const pageNav = document.querySelector('.page-nav');
  const fixClass = 'is-fixed';
  var section = document.querySelectorAll('.section-card');
  var sections = {};
  var i = 0;

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(section, function(e) {
    sections[e.id] = e.offsetTop;
  });

  window.onscroll = function() {
    if( window.pageYOffset > 56 ) {
       pageNav.classList.add(fixClass);
    }
    if( window.pageYOffset < 56 ) {
       pageNav.classList.remove(fixClass);
    }
    var scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i in sections) {
      if (sections[i] <= scrollPosition) {
        console.log(document.querySelector('.active'));
        document.querySelector('.active').setAttribute('class', ' ');
        document.querySelector('a[href*=' + i + ']').setAttribute('class', 'active');
      }
    }
  };
})();
```

But, if I do:

```
document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
        document.querySelector('a[href*=' + i + ']').classList.add('active');
```

This is the html:

```
      <nav id="page-nav" class="nav section-links">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#info">Info</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#videos">Videos</a>
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#stats">Statistics</a>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Please click the `<>` and make one or two snippets that are [mcve]s

Comment: remove * from second line of code..  document.querySelector('a[href=' + i + ']').classList.add('active');

Answer (score -1):

When you're setting the attributes, you're doing a `querySelector()` call *after* the DOM has loaded.

But for setting the class, you're using the `querySelector()` result that took place *before* the DOM was loaded.

So if you want to cache those elements so that you don't need to keep re-selecting them, then your script should not run until those elements exist. Try moving your script to the bottom of the `body` element.